# vue3 : after intall sass-loader : " TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'NormalModule') "

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an error when i want to run "npm run serve"

Complete errror :

```
  INFO  Starting development server...
  ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'NormalModule')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'NormalModule')
    at VueLoaderPlugin.apply ("***"\node_modules\vue-loader-v16\dist\pluginWebpack5.js:44:47)
    at webpack ("***"\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:51:13)
    at serve ("***"\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:163:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Is come after want to install sass-loader.

I have try to delete folder "node_modules" and after npm install but i have always this error.

```json
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-5",
        "axios": "^0.26.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "sass": "^1.54.0",
        "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
        "vue": "^3.0.0",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
        "vue3-html2pdf": "^1.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.15",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.15",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.15",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```